# Why is the run-time class of a Kotlin-collection a Java-class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In the "Kotlin for Java-Developers"-course by JetBrains (at Coursera) it is told, that Kotlin-code is compiled to byte-code directly. And that byte-code is then executed on the JVM.

But when I do:

```
var list = listOf<String>("A", "B", "C")
println(list::class) // => Prints "class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList"
```

Obviously the normal Java ArrayList is used underneath. So I confused ...

**Is Kotlin just some "more modern" syntax thing, which uses Java underneath?**

Practically some syntactic sugar, which is put on-top, so that one can write code in a nicier way. But underneath it's still the same old Java-thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is Kotlin just some "more modern" syntax thing, which uses Java underneath?

No.  You Kotlin source code >>is<< compiling to bytecodes.

But your code is using the `listof` Kotlin library function, and the implementation of that function is returning a value that is an instance of a Java class.

Why?

1. It was *probably* easier / quicker to implement it that way.  (Based on the type of the list object, we can infer that `listof` is simply calling `java.util.Arrays.asList(...)`.)
2. There is *possibly* no advantage in reimplementing it; e.g. no performance benefit.
3. There are *possibly* disadvantages; e.g. it is likely to cause problems for people who need their Kotlin code to be interoperable with Java which uses standard Java collection classes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I get it right, then the Kotlin-listOf is "wrapped-around" the Java-class in this case?

Comment: Not exactly.  It is a function that is returning a `list` that is implemented as a Java class.  Under the hood, I imagine that `listof` is calling `java.util.Arrays.asList` ... based on the type of the object you are seeing.  (But this is an implementation detail.  The spec for `listof` just says it returns a `list`.)